# ArrayLists agregar un nuevo objeto con diferentes datos

Tags: java, arraylist

Hola necesito ayuda para un proyecto no he podido terminar porque no se como hacer eso.

Bueno el problema consiste en que el proyecto es de Arraylist ese arraylist lo lleno de información sobre "proyectos" para eso le pido al usuario el numero de proy, nombre, presupuesto y porcentaje de avance del proy, lo que pasa es que si los pido pero que pasa si el usuario quiere meter otro proyecto, hace lo mismo pero seria un proyecto con diferentes datos.

En un menu tengo una opcion que dice "Consultar proyecto especifico" para eso pido el numero de proy y automaticamente el prog me tira la info de dicho proyecto dependiendo del numero.

y cuando trato de hacer eso me sale es toda la info que he metido o sea que si el numero del primer proyc introducido es 1 y el segundo es 13 y el usuario quiere imprimir solo la info del 1 proy teclea el 1 pero tambien sale la info del proy 13 porque se imprimi todo todo.

Ayuda por favor!

Aquí el código que he escrito:

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
  ArrayList P1 = new ArrayList();

  Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

  int op = 0, num, sn, x = 01, i, n;

  String nom;

  double pt, pr = 0;

  do {
   op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " REGISTRO DE PROYECTOS\n" 
    + "\n 1 - Registrar datos de proyecto\n"

    + "2 - Actualizar porcentaje de avance de proyectos\n"

    + "3 - Consultar un proyecto en especifico\n"

    + "4 - Mostrar datos de todos los proyectos\n"

    + "5 - Eliminar un registro de preyecto en especifico\n"

    + "6 - Eliminar todos los registros de proyecto\n "));



   switch (op) {

    case 1:
     System.out.println("*************DATOS DEL PROYECTO *************");
     System.out.println("\n");
     System.out.println("Numero del proyecto:");
     num = sc.nextInt();
     P1.add(num);
     System.out.println("Nombre del proyecto:");
     nom = sc.next();
     P1.add(nom);
     System.out.println("Presupuesto para el proyecto:");
     pt = sc.nextDouble();
     P1.add(pt);
     System.out.println("Porcentaje de avance del proyecto:");
     pr = sc.nextDouble();
     P1.add(pr);
     break;


    case 2:

     System.out.println("Nuevo porcentaje de proyecto:");
     pr = sc.nextInt();
     if (pr == 100) {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*****ACTUALIZACION*****\n" + "PROYECTO CONCLUIDO");
     } else {
      JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*****ACTUALIZACION*****\n" + "PROYECTO EN EJECUCION");
     }

     System.out.println("\n");

     System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
     System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
     System.out.println("\n");

    case 3:
     System.out.println("*****CONSULTA DE PROYECTO*****");


     for (i = 0; i <= P1.size() - 1; i++) {
      System.out.println(P1.get(i));

     }

   }
   System.out.println("Desea volver al menu (SI = 1 / NO = 2)");
   sn = sc.nextInt();
  } while (sn == 1);
```

Comment: Como hago para solo imprimir esos 4 datos sin que se impriman los otros que pertenecen a un proyecto diferente

Comment: Mira [ask] <-ACA para que tu pregunta sea mejor recibida. Tambien, aprovecha    y haz el [tour] <-ACA para entender mejor como funcionamos y de paso obtener tu primera [medalla](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/badges)! usa el boton [edit] si necesitas agregar informacion. Vas a tener que mostrarnos el codigo que te trae problemas para que podamos ayudarte.

Comment: dime sabes lo que es un array? porque hacer `array[2]` es equivalente a hacer `arrayList.get(2)`. Dicho esto tu tienes un ciclo (for) que recorre toda la lista imprimiendo todos los valores pero solo quieres uno en específico, solo accede al que necesitas con el indice que corresponde

Comment: Al parecer el código está incompleto o difiere con la información que proporcionas, ya que la opción 3 de tu menú parece ser la opción 4, ya que no estás filtrando nada, estas mostrando todo el contenido del ArrayList, modifica tu código para tener una mejor ayuda, o ese puede ser tu error.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Una de las opciones que pude encontrar fue haciendolo POO, creando una clase proyecto:

```
public class proyecto {

    protected int num_proj;
    protected String name_proj;
    protected double estimate_proj;
    protected double percentage_proj;

    public proyecto(){}

    public proyecto(int num_proj, String name_proj, double estimate_proj, double percentage_proj) {
        this.num_proj = num_proj;
        this.name_proj = name_proj;
        this.estimate_proj = estimate_proj;
        this.percentage_proj = percentage_proj;
    }

    public int getNum_proj() {
        return num_proj;
    }

    public void setNum_proj(int num_proj) {
        this.num_proj = num_proj;
    }

    public String getName_proj() {
        return name_proj;
    }

    public void setName_proj(String name_proj) {
        this.name_proj = name_proj;
    }

    public double getEstimate_proj() {
        return estimate_proj;
    }

    public void setEstimate_proj(double estimate_proj) {
        this.estimate_proj = estimate_proj;
    }

    public double getPercentage_proj() {
        return percentage_proj;
    }

    public void setPercentage_proj(double percentage_proj) {
        this.percentage_proj = percentage_proj;
    }
}
```

Luego En la clase main seria nada mas modificar los pasos:

```
public static void main(String[] args){

        ArrayList<proyecto> Proyectos = new ArrayList();

        Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);

        int op = 0, num, sn, x = 01, i, n;

        String nom;

        double pt, pr = 0;

        do {
            op = Integer.parseInt(JOptionPane.showInputDialog(null, " REGISTRO DE PROYECTOS\n"
                    + "\n 1 - Registrar datos de proyecto\n"

                    + "2 - Actualizar porcentaje de avance de proyectos\n"

                    + "3 - Consultar un proyecto en especifico\n"

                    + "4 - Mostrar datos de todos los proyectos\n"

                    + "5 - Eliminar un registro de preyecto en especifico\n"

                    + "6 - Eliminar todos los registros de proyecto\n "));



            switch (op) {

                case 1:
                    proyecto p = new proyecto();
                    System.out.println("*************DATOS DEL PROYECTO *************");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    System.out.println("Numero del proyecto:");
                    num = sc.nextInt();
                    p.setNum_proj(num);
                    System.out.println("Nombre del proyecto:");
                    nom = sc.next();
                    p.setName_proj(nom);
                    System.out.println("Presupuesto para el proyecto:");
                    pt = sc.nextDouble();
                    p.setEstimate_proj(pt);
                    System.out.println("Porcentaje de avance del proyecto:");
                    pr = sc.nextDouble();
                    p.setPercentage_proj(pr);
                    Proyectos.add(p);
                    break;


                case 2:

                    System.out.println("Digite numero del proyecto al que quiere editar el porcentaje");
                    proyecto ps = new proyecto();
                    int find = sc.nextInt();
                    int pos = 0;
                    for (int j = 0; j < Proyectos.size(); j++){
                        if(Proyectos.get(j).getNum_proj()==find){
                            ps = Proyectos.get(j);
                            pos = j;
                            break;
                        }
                    }
                    System.out.println("Nuevo porcentaje de proyecto:");
                    pr = sc.nextInt();
                    if (pr == 100) {
                        ps.setPercentage_proj(pr);
                        Proyectos.set(pos, ps);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*****ACTUALIZACION*****\n" + "PROYECTO CONCLUIDO");
                    } else {
                        ps.setPercentage_proj(pr);
                        Proyectos.set(pos, ps);
                        JOptionPane.showMessageDialog(null, "*****ACTUALIZACION*****\n" + "PROYECTO EN EJECUCION");
                    }

                    System.out.println("\n");

                    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("***************************************************************************");
                    System.out.println("\n");
                    break;
                case 3:
                    System.out.println("*****CONSULTA DE PROYECTO*****");
                    System.out.println("Digite numero de proyecto a consultar");
                    int search = sc.nextInt();
                    for (int j = 0; j < Proyectos.size(); j++){
                        if(Proyectos.get(j).getNum_proj()==search){
                            System.out.println("Numero: " + Proyectos.get(j).getNum_proj());
                            System.out.println("Nombre: " + Proyectos.get(j).getName_proj());
                            System.out.println("Presupuesto: " + Proyectos.get(j).getEstimate_proj());
                            System.out.println("Avance: " + Proyectos.get(j).getPercentage_proj() + "%");

                            break;
                        }
                    }


            }
            System.out.println("Desea volver al menu (SI = 1 / NO = 2)");
            sn = sc.nextInt();
        } while (sn == 1);

    }
```

Ya eso seria todo

Comment: JDR Asdrubal Hernandez MUCHAS GRACIAS PERO MUCHAS GRACIAS ENSERIO TE LO AGRADEZCO ES PRIMERA VEZ QUE CONSULTO AQUI ASI QUE QUIERO SABER SI PUEDO AGRADECERTE DE ALGUNA FORMA VI QUE DAN MEDALLAS Y ESAS COSAS. MUCHAS GRACIAS DE NUEVO Y ESTUDIARE EL CODIGO HABER COMO LO HICISTE :D UN ABRAZO ENORME

Comment: ERES MUY BUENO ^.^

Comment: Dale no hay problema para eso es esta pagina, aunque soy nuevo y pues me convenci a mi mismo para ayudar a otros. asi que no hay de que. sigue estudiando para que vayas mejorando. Con que coloques que mi respuesta es acertada basta.

Answer (score 0):

En el caso de sacar un proyecto específico veo que es la opción 3 la cual es

```
case 3:
     System.out.println("*****CONSULTA DE PROYECTO*****");
     for (i = 0; i <= P1.size() - 1; i++) {
      System.out.println(P1.get(i));
     }
   }
```

Ahí lo que estás haciendo es imprimir una linea de texto y de seguido recorrer el array P1 y enseñar todos y cada uno de los resultados. Para coger solo 1 resultado debería ser

```
 case 3:
         System.out.println("*****CONSULTA DE PROYECTO*****");
         /* variable 'i' será el ID introducido por el usuario, por lo que se deberá de recoger anteriormente su respuesta. */
          System.out.println(P1.get(i));
       }
```

Comment: Gracias Kraako V pero una consulta, alli imprimo un dato de todo el arraylist? Porque son proyectos que tienen numero, nombre, presupuesto y porcentaje pero como hago para imprimir solamente esos 4 datos quiero decir que si tengo 2 proyectos introducidos cada uno con si numero, nombre... tengo que ser capaz de llamar a uno de los 2 proyectos y que me de numero, nombre... de ese proyecto sin tocar la info que tengo del otro proy, no se si me explico :\ . Por ejm: tengo 2 proyectos cuando quiero imprimir un proyecto en espf. lo llamo por su numero y me tira la info de dicho proy.